# Is there a reliable, cross-platform (on *nix anyway) way to create a temporary file on another device?

Tags: unix, shared-memory, mount, tmpfs

I'm trying to write a test case for some code that should iterates over a filesystem tree, but should stop if a file is on another device. In writing tests for it, I considered creating a file in `/dev/shm`, symlinking to it from my test directory, and then checking that it isn't read, but `/dev/shm` seems to be Linux-specific. `mount`-ing a `tmpfs` could be an option, but it requires root...

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I was thinking in creating your own dummy filesystem for this purpose. The reading [Does mount always require root privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20838/40596) suggests that you may be able to without root, as long as you are able to configure `/etc/fstab` before. And this of course needs root at least once. Can you do that or you are looking for a fully non-root way?

Comment: Devices have a major and minor number.  The only ways a directory tree can have  multiple devices in the sense you mean (ignoring  zpools for example) is for there to exist one of: a mountpoint, or a symbolic link.  The stat answer covers that in both cases. @RolandSmith

Comment: The short answer to the question in the title is "no", since it is possible to have complete systems living in only one device (i.e. the root file system).

Answer (score 3):

Try FUSE : http://fuse.sourceforge.net/. FUSE is supported under Linux, FreeBSD/NetBSD, OpenSolaris, and Mac OS X, and hence, whatever toy filesystem you use for your tests (see http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/wiki/FileSystems/) will

a) be cross-platform
b) in user-space (no root required)
and
c) not require too much of test scaffolding to set up and tear down

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "device". Do you consider files on different filesystems on the same disk on the same device or not?

Using `stat(2)` you can get the numeric ID from the filesystem containing the field in the `st_dev` field of the returned `struct stat`. That way you can distinguish between filesystems.

Comment: "Different device" means the value for `st_dev` returned by `stat(2)` is different, as you point out.

My question is not about how to distinguish between files on different devices.